# Better accessibility label for a clickable table view cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitableview, accessibility

We have a `UITableView` with clickable `UITableViewCell`s, which, when clicked, take you to another view. The default accessibility text for a `UITableViewCell` reads out the label of the cell. There is no indication of the cell being clickable. We think that it would be more helpful to include such an indicator in the accessibility text. Something along the lines of "A row labeled $label". How can we achieve this? Also, what is an accepted practice in iOS land in this regard?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My immediate problem was solved by doing the following:

```
uiTableViewCell.accessibilityTraits = UIAccessibilityTraitButton
```

This causes VoiceOver to follow up the reading of the elements label with "button".

Comment: Now "UIAccessibilityTraits.button" on more recent Swift versions :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can add

```
cell.accessibilityLabel = "text you want to be there"
```

in cellForRowAtIndexPath method it will work as you want i believe

Comment: It still needs to continue including original text too. How to make that happen?

Comment: in the same method you are doing this arleady so add text you are setting to cell.textLabel to cell.accessibilityLabel :)